# Use qDebug in unit testing Qt

Tags: unit-testing, qt, qdebug

I wanted to use qDebug in the Qt unit testing, i had written the code of qDebug but it is not getting diplayed
I even used

```
ctest -R alkimia-alkinvoice -VV
```

But even this shows only the location where the error is coming from.
but i needed to use qDebug for more information about the error

Comment: It's known "feature" of qDebug ) Could you please provide some code with it? Why you don't want to use standard output streams?

Comment: Are you running under Windows?

Comment: Just as an additional tip for future readers, `qDebug` output (and similar) is suppressed if tests are run using the [`-silent`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtest-overview.html#test-log-detail-options) command line argument

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To quote the documentation for qDebug()..

> Calls the message handler with the debug message msg. If no message
>   handler has been installed, the message is printed to stderr. **Under
>   Windows, the message is sent to the console, if it is a console
>   application; otherwise, it is sent to the debugger.** This function does
>   nothing if QT_NO_DEBUG_OUTPUT was defined during compilation.

I'm going to assume you are running under Windows, sorry if that is incorrect. `qDebug()` output under Windows is converted into Win32 `OutputDebugString()` API calls. If you are running under a debugger/IDE that can hook into that API then you should see the debug outputs in one of that program's windows.

If you add `CONFIG+=console` to your .pro file and rebuild/run your program from the console, you should see the debug output.

Comment: thanks for the reply but i am working on linux, and i havent even used QT_NO_DEBUG_OUPUT in the cmake files

Comment: Ok, well that is certainly strange. I'll leave the answer up for anyone that encounters this problem under windows. Good luck!

Comment: Thanks, I dont know where I made the mistake but its all working now...must be some sillly mistake....thanks